# Eclipse 2019-06 PHP autocomplete (content-assist) not working

Tags: php, autocomplete, eclipse-pdt

I've juste installed the latest version of Eclipse, Eclipse 2019-06.
Infortunatly, the PHP content-assist or autocomplete doesn't work anymore **when working on remote system**.
I've searched for solutions but didn't find anything...

The files are on a remote workspace, not local. It was OK with and old version of Eclipse (Mars), there are illustrations above.

I've checked in the preferences at **PHP->Editor->Content assist**, the Auto-Activation is checked.

Here is an illustration :
https://ibb.co/MD72NKv

With an old version, it worked well :
https://ibb.co/R7xQShL

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Then I suggest you report a bug to the Eclipse team

Comment: Please add example code to your question to reproduce this issue and show a screenshot of the PHP editor and the _Project Explorer_ view.

Comment: @RiggsFolly For a bug report this is too little information and I guess this is not a bug, but e.g. the PHP file is not contained in a PHP project or opened with the wrong editor. You probably also mean report it to the Eclipse PDT project (there is no Eclipse team, like there is no Apache team).

Comment: Thank you, I have added images to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK the problem is solved.
It occured only with files on remote system, not on a local file in the workspace.

Thi solution here work perfectly :
https://drupalsun.com/patrick/2011/07/25/how-setup-eclipse-php-pdt-remote-system-explorer-theme-manager-and-drupal-plugins

```
Now we are going to use RSE to edit an eclipse RSE .project file. So in your 'Remote System' tab open up your local files and navigate to you workspace folder. Look for a folder called 'RemoteSystemsTempFiles' and open that. Now you are going to edit the '.project' file. Open up that file.

You are going to add two line in between the <natures> tag, those lines are 

<nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature> 

Save that file and restart eclipse. If you did everything correctly you should now have auto complete that will look like so
```